# How to get the last sold price in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a query that will show me basic item information as well as the total qty shipped (for all orders),last date that the item was sold and the price it was sold at. I cant figure out how to get the last sold price.  This is what I have so far,

```
SELECT
    item_id 
    ,item_desc
    ,sum(qty_shipped) AS 'Total Qty Shipped' 
    ,count(item_id) AS 'No of times Shipped'  
    ,max(invoice_date) AS 'Last Invoice_date'
    ,unit_price AS 'Last Price'
FROM sales_history_report
WHERE
    item_id = '1234'
    AND year_for_period >= '2017'
    AND sales_location_id like '10'
GROUP BY
    item_id
    ,item_desc
    ,unit_price
```

with this query I am getting all of the lines that this item is on. It looks like this right now,

Item_id,Item_desc,Total_QTY_shipped,no_of_times_shipped,Last_Invoice_date,Last_price
1234,Item 1234,4,1,2014-10-15,2.47
1234,Item 1234,6,1,2014-09-20,2.519

But I am looking for
Item_id,Item_desc,Total_QTY_shipped,no_of_times_shipped,Last_Invoice_date,Last_price
1234,Item 1234,10,2,2014-10-15,2.47

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select item_id, item_desc,
       sum(qty_shipped) as [Total Qty Shipped],
       count(item_id) as [No of times Shipped], 
       max(invoice_date) as Max_Date,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then unit_price end) as [Last Price],
from (select shr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item_id order by invoice_date desc) as seqnum
      from sales_history_report shr
     ) shr
where item_id = 1234 and
      year_for_period >= 2017 and
      sales_location_id like '10'
group by item_id, item_desc;
```

Comments:

- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- The columns in the `GROUP BY` define the rows in the result set.  I don't think you want `unit_price` in it.
- Do not use single quotes for numeric constants.  I assume `item_id` an the year are numeric.